# Sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(n(n+1)(2n+1))}{6n!}}$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have gotten it to simplify to $\frac{1}{3}$$\sum{\frac{n^3}{n!}}$+$\frac{1}{2}$$\sum{\frac{n^2}{n!}}$+$\frac{1}{6}$$\sum{\frac{n}{n!}}$ all of these as n goes to $\infty$ but cant go any further. Please help.

Comment: Hint: For $n\geq 3$, $\frac{2n^{3}+3n^{2}+n}{6n!} = \frac{1}{\left(n-1\right)!} + \frac{5/2}{\left(n-2\right)!} + \frac{1/3}{\left(n-3\right)!}$.

Comment: Your sums start from $n=0$, is that correct? The first two can be solved by clever manipulation with the index of summation.

Answer (score 5):

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(n(n+1)(2n+1))}{6n!}}=
{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(n + 1\right) \left(2 n + 1\right)}{6 \left(n - 1\right)!}}=
{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(n + 2\right) \left(2 n + 3\right)}{6 n!}}$$

$$={\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{3 \left(n - 1\right)!} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{7}{6 \left(n - 1\right)!} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}}$$
The last sum is equal to $e$ while the middle one is a manipulation done to the expansion of $e$.

I'll just solve for $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{\left(n - 1\right)!}$$
It is equal to $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n+1}{n!}$$
which is again equal to $${\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left(n - 1\right)!} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}}$$
Now these two are again $e$ or manipulation of $e$.

I hope you can continue from here.

Answer (score 3):

An efficient solution method is to attempt to write the numerator $n(n+1)(2n+1)$ as a linear combination of the polynomials $n$, $n(n-1)$, and $n(n-1)(n-2)$, since we know that $n! = n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)!$.  To this end, we are interested in coefficients $a, b, c$ satisfying

$$an + bn(n-1) + cn(n-1)(n-2) = n(n+1)(2n+1), \tag{1}$$ which after rearranging, becomes
$$(c-2)n^3 + (b-3c-3)n^2 + (a-b+2c-1)n = 0. \tag{2}$$
Since we require this to be true for all positive integers $n$, it follows that
$$c = 2, \quad b = 9, \quad a = 6. \tag{3}$$
Hence
$$\begin{align}
\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n!} &= \frac{(6n) + (9n(n-1)) + (2n(n-1)(n-2))}{6n!} \\
&= \frac{n}{n(n-1)!} + \frac{3n(n-1)}{2n(n-1)(n-2)!} + \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)!} \\
&= \frac{1}{(n-1)!} + \frac{3}{2(n-2)!} + \frac{1}{3(n-3)!}, \tag{4}
\end{align}$$
whenever $n \ge 3$.  We can also stipulate that if $n \in \{1, 2\}$, then any terms in $(4)$ for which the factorial is undefined will evaluate to $0$; therefore, the desired sum is
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n!} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-1)!} + \frac{3}{2} \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-2)!} + \frac{1}{3} \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-3)!}, \tag{5}$$ and the rest is trivial.  The key insight here is to express the numerator as a suitable linear combination, thus eliminating the need to do additional massaging of the sums in the subsequent step.